# Closest distance that two unrelated spacecraft have come while both in heliocentric orbits?

Tags: history, mission-design, deep-space, record

In 2015 [STEREO A and B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STEREO) passed each other passing roughly behind the Sun at the same time from opposite directions as seen from Earth. But these two are part of a single mission, put into these orbits that would inevitably pass each other.

**Question:** What is the closest distance that two unrelated spacecraft have come while both in heliocentric orbits?

In order to avoid the mess of all the Mars orbiters or similar situations, neither should be in an orbit around a planet or any other solar-system body besides the Sun.

---

[image: Animation of STEREO trajectory relative to Sun and Earth]

> Animation of STEREO trajectory relative to Sun and Earth

Plot of [JPL Horizons data](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi), they come within almost exactly 16.0000 million kilometers on almost exactly April Fools day. *Coincidence?* :-)

[image: Plot of JPL Horizons data, they come within almost exactly 16.0000 million kilometers on almost exactly April Fools day in California. Coincidence?]